# How does the SqLiteDatabase database rawQuery() method work?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how this works, but I am lost how the bindings happen? Whats the need to get the valueOf()? Aren't the arguments in the string array suppose to be just strings?

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b "+
"ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

I also want to join tables, but not sure how how to set it up correctly, at least the arguments for the String array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the two lines of code are examples you found some place? String.valueOf is a standard java function. If propertyId is an int, it converts the int to a String.
You can leave out the argument String[], and hard code your arguments in the sql string, but that is not good programming practice. I am not sure I understand your question about "bindings", but what happens is that the value of peropertyId (converted to String by valueOf) is inserted in your query at the question mark.

Comment: What happens when there are two question marks. Do they have to match? (2, 2 or 3, 3)?

Comment: The reference documentation says "You may include ?s in where clause in the query", so you just include a number of ?s and the arguments will be inserted in the order you specify them. Please read the android api docs.

Comment: I did. But its not clear as to how it does it. But thank you.